# RTK Query: maxRetries && backoff

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query to perform my API calls.
I have a mutation which I want to retry fetching if got the an error response.
I also want to control the delay between the retries.

** Note: I tried maxRetries, but I have no control over the delay between retries

** Note 2: after digging deep, I found the "retryCondition" fn under "extraOptions". Also, I checked the "backoff". but I am not sure how to use these together to control the delay.
I searched over the internet && found nothing about backoff
Also the documentation mentions the "retry" briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the docs don't surface this feature well enough and I had to go spelunking in the repo to find the information. The `retry` function takes 2 arguments, first is the base query function and second is a default options (*`RetryOptions`*) configuration object.

See [`RetryOptions` type declaration](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/query/retry.ts#L43-L64):

> ```
> export type RetryOptions = {
>   /**
>    * Function used to determine delay between retries
>    */
>   backoff?: (attempt: number, maxRetries: number) => Promise<void>
> } & (
>   | {
>       /**
>        * How many times the query will be retried (default: 5)
>        */
>       maxRetries?: number
>       retryCondition?: undefined
>     }
>   | {
>       /**
>        * Callback to determine if a retry should be attempted.
>        * Return `true` for another retry and `false` to quit trying prematurely.
>        */
>       retryCondition?: RetryConditionFunction
>       maxRetries?: undefined
>     }
> )
> ```

The `backoff` property is what you're interested in

```js
(attempt: number, maxRetries: number) => Promise<void>
```

It's a function that takes attempt and max retries arguments and returns a Promise. Fortunately there's already a default backoff function you can reference:

> ```
> /**
>  * Exponential backoff based on the attempt number.
>  *
>  * @remarks
>  * 1. 600ms * random(0.4, 1.4)
>  * 2. 1200ms * random(0.4, 1.4)
>  * 3. 2400ms * random(0.4, 1.4)
>  * 4. 4800ms * random(0.4, 1.4)
>  * 5. 9600ms * random(0.4, 1.4)
>  *
>  * @param attempt - Current attempt
>  * @param maxRetries - Maximum number of retries
>  */
> async function defaultBackoff(attempt: number = 0, maxRetries: number = 5) {
>   const attempts = Math.min(attempt, maxRetries)
>
>   const timeout = ~~((Math.random() + 0.4) * (300 << attempts)) // Force a positive int in the case we make this an option
>   await new Promise((resolve) =>
>     setTimeout((res: any) => resolve(res), timeout)
>   )
> }
> ```

IMO this is a pretty good default function, but you could construct your own if necessary.

Examples:

1 second, 2 seconds, 3 seconds, ...maxRetries seconds

```js
const customBackOff = async (attempt = 0, maxRetries = 5) => {
  const attempts = Math.min(attempt, maxRetries);

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, attempts * 1000);
  });
};
```

1 second each retry

```js
const customBackOff = async (attempt = 0, maxRetries = 5) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
};
```

Lookup in array.

```js
const backoffDelays = [500, 2000, 5000];

const customBackOff = async (attempt = 0, maxRetries = 5) => {
  const attempts = Math.min(backoffDelays.length - 1, maxRetries);

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, backoffDelays[attempts]);
  });
};
```

Follow the example from the documentation to decorate your base query function.

```js
const customBaseQuery = retry(
  fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  { backoff: customBackOff, maxRetries: 5 }
);

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: customBaseQuery,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ....
  }),
});
```

Comment: very helpful 
Thank you 
I used 
const customBackOff = async (attempt = 0, maxRetries = 5) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
};
I used it on a single endpoint 
&& works fine